# Is calling an object's destructor equivalent to calling delete on the object?

Tags: c++, class, memory, destructor

```
class TrieTree{
private:
    string ch;
    unordered_map<string, TrieTree*> child;
public:
    TrieTree(string val): ch(val){}
    ~TrieTree(){
        for(unordered_map<string, TrieTree*>::iterator itr = this->child.begin();
            itr != this->child.end();
            itr++){

            (itr->second)->~TrieTree();
        }
    }
};
```

I'm concerned if the above destructor will create memory leak since I'm unsure if calling an object's destructor is equivalent to calling delete to the object. I cannot directly call delete on the object since the intention is to recursively delete the object's child. By calling `delete (itr->second);` after `(itr->second)->~TrieTree();` I'm getting segmentation faults, so I'm guessing the object might have been deleted after its destructor?

Comment: `delete` is equivalent to the destructor call followed by freeing the storage which the object occupied. If you use `delete` as well as the explicit destructor call then you therefore call the destructor twice, which causes undefined behaviour. Your rationale for not just using `delete` makes no sense.

Comment: also this class does not follow Rule of Three(/five/zero)

Comment: consider using `unordered_map<string, unique_ptr<TrieTree>>` if that suits your application (we cannot tell just based on what is posted), then you don't have to do any manual memory management at all

Comment: Or Rule of Four (and half).

Comment: In general, the way to clean up a tree is to delete the children of a node and then delete the node.

Comment: @PeteBecker As long as the tree has less than linearly growing bound for its depth. Otherwise you risk overflowing the stack with large trees. With unbalanced trees, one should use iterative algorithm.

Comment: Use `delete itr->second;`. That will recurse exactly as you want.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is calling an object's destructor equivalent to calling delete on the object?

No, it is not equivalent.

Calling destructor of an object destroys it.

Calling `delete` on a pointer destroys the pointed object and deallocates the memory. Behaviour is undefined unless the pointed was returned from allocating `new`.

If you allocate memory with `new` and only call the destructor without deallocating, then you will leak memory. If you destroy the object and attempt to use `delete` while the pointed object is destroyed, then the behaviour of your program will be undefined.

---

P.S. Avoid using owning bare pointers.